# Email using shell script

Tags: shell-script, email

Is there a possibility to add multiple e-mails to a single variable so that when the shell script is run, it sends a mail to all the specified emails?

Comment: u will have to use shell script to get different email ids & run mail command with each email ids. Probably you can use a array variable to store email ids or get it from a file. Click here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426077/how-to-send-a-mail-with-a-message-in-unix-script)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the command you use to send email to a single address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155923/sending-a-mail-from-a-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use `sendmail` or `mail` in your script (which both expect a comma separated string as list of recipients), you can concatenate the IDs (or directly write them as such a list):

```bash
$: recipients="rec1@example.com, rec2@example.com, rec3@example.com"
```

or concatenating:

```
$: base_recipients="important1@example.com, important2@example.com"
$: full_recipients="$base_recipients, special@example.com"

$: echo $full_recipients
important1@example.com, important2@example.com, special@example.com
```

The following would be an example sending a mail with `sendmail` to 3 different mail IDs:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

recipients="reci1@example.com, another@example.com, friend3@different.com"
subject="Mail to you all"
from="your_mail@something.com"

message_txt="Hi all!\n This is a message to all 3 of you!.\n cheers, Me."

/usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" << EOF
subject:$subject
from:$from
$message_txt
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my code using mail array:

```
MAILADDR=(mail1@example.com mail2@example.com mail3@example.com)
for i in "${MAILADDR[@]}"
    do
         echo "Mail test..." | mail -s "Mail test subject..." $i
    done
```