# Email using shell script using email address from external flat file

Tags: shell-script, email

I'm using alexkowalski script from [Email using shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140684/email-using-shell-script)

```
MAILADDR=(mail1@example.com, mail2@example.com, mail3@example.com)
for i in "${MAILADDR[@]}"
    do
         echo "Mail test..." | mail -s "Mail test subject..." $i
    done
```

My question is how to read `MAILADDR` array from an external flat file?

And how to insert an external flat file replacing the body of the email as in

```
echo"/home/user/information-for-any-user.txt"  | mail -s "Mail test subject..." $i ??
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Don't put commas in your array declaration: array elements are separated by whitespace only (unless you have redefined $IFS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "external flat file" from which the email addresses are taken from doesn't look too funny (is well formatted), you could use something like that :

```
mail -s "My subject" $(cat /this/is/the/external/flat/file.txt) < /home/user/information-for-any-user.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can provide multiple address on the `mail` command.

1. assume there are no glob chars in the flat file, and the email addresses are separated by any whitespace:

   ```
   echo "Mail test..." | mail -s "Mail test subject..." $(< address.file)
   ```
2. read the newline-separated list of addresses into a bash array

   ```
   mapfile -t addr < address.file
   echo "Mail test..." | mail -s "Mail test subject..." "${addr[@]}"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, combining both answers did the job.

mapfile -t addr < /home/user/address-file #(one email address per line)

echo "$(cat < /home/user/information-for-any-user)" | mail -s "My subject" "${addr[@]}"

Cheers